# Qual a diferença entre git reset -- <file_name> e git reset HEAD <file_name>?

Tags: git

Para remover arquivos da staged area utilizo do comando:

```
 $ git reset HEAD <file_name>
```

Entretanto acidentalmente apliquei o comando:

```
$ git reset <file_name>
```

Esqueci o **HEAD** do comando.

Ao faze-lo recebi a mensagem:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'class/control/C_UsuarioFerias.php': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]'

Interpretei a mesma e em seguida apliquei o comando:

```
$ git reset -- <file_name>
```

Portanto o arquivo foi removido da staged area. Ambos os comandos realizam a mesma ação, mas há alguma diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe diferença entre os comandos abaixo.

```
git reset HEAD <file_name>
git reset <file_name>
```

O que ocorre é que, caso não mencione o `HEAD`, o Git vai usar por padrão o `HEAD`. Isto está descrito na [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> The `<tree-ish>/<commit>` defaults to HEAD in all forms.

Creio que na maioria dos locais o pessoal sempre passa o comando com o parâmetro `HEAD` para deixar a explicação mais didática e não criar confusões sobre onde o comando está sendo aplicado de verdade.

[Sobre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217853/what-does-the-double-dash-option-do-on-git-reset) o uso do hífen duplo `--` (*double dash* ou *double hyfhen*), é para desfazer uma ambiguidade, caso exista um arquivo e uma *branch* com o mesmo nome:

```
criar-usuario     # arquivo
criar-usuario     # branch
```

Se o arquivo começar com hífen, o uso do `--` também é necessário.

Answer (score -1):

O git reset permite especificar o commit. É o que você está especificando em HEAD, pois HEAD é o commit mais recente. Poderia ser qualquer outro commit do passado.

Comment: Por que do negativo?